# How to send request to HTTP POST request to server

Tags: android, http-post

Hello I am using  two buttons which on click show date picker dialog and time picker dialog.
I have a spinner.

I want to send the user input value to a php server.
What should I do for the client side code?

Here is my code:

```
public class DineOutActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
   /******************time picker**************/
        private TextView mTimeDisplay;
           private Button mPickTime;
           private int mHour;
           private int mMinute;
           private int mAmPm;

           static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=1;

        static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /********************spinner***********/

        Spinner food = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> foodadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        foodadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        food.setAdapter(foodadapter);
        /**pick date*/

        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
       /**pick time**/

        mPickTime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        // add a click listener to the button
        mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                     public void onClick(View v) {

                           showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                     }
              });

        // get the current time
        final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mAmPm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

        // display the current date
       upTimeDisplay();


/*****************************pick date***********************************/
        // add a click listener to the button
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        // get the current date
        final Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int mDst = date.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        int mAmPm = date.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

        // display the current date (this method is below)
        updateDisplay();
    }

    // updates the date in the TextView




   private void upTimeDisplay()
   {
     //  mTimeDisplay.setText(new  
           //    StringBuilder().append(pad(mHour)).append(":").append(pad(mMinute)).append(pad(mAmPm)));
       mTimeDisplay.setText(new  
                  StringBuilder().append(mHour).append(":").append(mMinute));
       mTimeDisplay.setTextColor(R.color.green);
   }
  /** private Object pad(int mMinute2) {

       if(mMinute2>=10)
              return String.valueOf(mMinute2);
       else
              return "0"+String.valueOf(mMinute2);
}**/

   private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mtimeSetListener=new  
           TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

mHour=hourOfDay;
mMinute=minute;
int ampm;

upTimeDisplay();
}
};


    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
        mDateDisplay.setTextColor(R.color.green);
                 //   .append(mHour).append("_")
                  //  .append(mMinute).append("_")));
    }

    // the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                    mDay);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,mtimeSetListener,mHour,mMinute,false);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am using mPickDate as the button which opens to a DatePickerDialog
mPickTime as the button which on click opens TimePicker Dialog
One Spinner (spinner1) to get the list of item.
mDateDisplay to show the date which is edited by user after clicking DatePickerDialog.
mTimeDisplay to show the time which is edited by user after clicking TimePickerDialog.

I want the string values of user input of DatePickerDialog,TimePickerDialog and spinner to send to server as HTTP post . Please tell me how to do ?I want the detail code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the tutorials [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html) or [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) and you may wish to go through [Android Developer HTTP Post](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
public void postData() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "blablabla"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", "yourdate"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but where will it get the nameValuePair from the user input, I mean how will it map with the dialogs and spinner.

Comment: also it will store the date and time in server how will I make the format to "YYYY/MM/DD" or "DD/MM/YYYY"

Comment: Did you write this code by yourself? no way you are asking me this ¬¬

Comment: What is the use of nameValyePairs,

Comment: I what to send the string to mysql , how can i do the request

Answer (score 3):

```
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    String downloadedString= null;

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    //for registerhttps://te
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url here");
    //add data
    try{
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", "harsh"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", "chandel"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "mike.bulurt66@gmail.com"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", "944566778"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "mikebulurt"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "qwert"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_duid", "986409987"));

        //add data
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bfrd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in),1024);
        String line;
        while((line = bfrd.readLine()) != null)
            stringbuilder.append(line);

        downloadedString = stringbuilder.toString();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("downloadedString:in login:::"+downloadedString);


    return downloadedString;
```